# How can two programs have the same path?

Tags: windows, path, music

I don't know if this is the appropriate section for asking such a question. It's about a music program I downloaded from the official website without any "extra". I've been very careful.
Well, actually I found on my desktop two different programs which have the same file location (path).

I even recorded a video so that you can understand better what I am trying to say. It's quite curious, interesting....
[Video from YouTube](https://youtu.be/Qps_P45x7QU)

Thank you.

Comment: As afar as the OS is concerned, as long as they have different file names, you could put every single executable on your computer in one folder.

Comment: If you take a look at the video I linked (so that you can see actually the files on my desktop), you'll see there is ONE EXE FILE.
The second shortcut on the desktop comes from the same path ("yct.exe") but with something added, that is, "/MP3 DOWNLOADER"
I never saw such a thing. It's the first time it happens.

Comment: So it is not two programs with the same path it is one program run two different ways. If you had have written that information in the question people wouldn't have to go watch a video.

Answer (score 3):

- "*aTube Catcher*" is a shortcut that launches without arguments - `yct.exe`
- "*Music Search MP3*" is a shortcut that launches *with* an argument - `yct.exe /MP3DOWNLOADER`

This argument can change the behaviour of the application entirely - in this case, it presents a different window - you may even be able to locate this window within the application when launched without any arguments.

Comment: That's true. Actually the MP3Downloader launches a window that can be launched within the first window without arguments. It looks like a simpler way to launch a specific feature of the main program. Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: What do you mean "_remove it_"? If you want to click on the shortcut without opening that window, then remove the `/MP3DOWNLOADER` from the "_Target_" box.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same executable but first is called as-is (`yct.exe`) and the second time is called with a flag `/MP3DOWNLOADER`. This flag indicates to the execute file to do something different.

Comment: All right, but is it dangerous? Is it a malicious thing? How can I delete the MP3DOWNLOADER thing? In the previous versions of this program, there was no Mp3 downloader at all !!

Comment: There is no separate mp3downloader thing. You can delete the shortcut with the mp3downloaded switch, but the functionality is built into the program.